# Link using a PHP Variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've created a database and am trying to make profile pages for users using id's from that database. The problem I am having is that the variable storing the users should be included in the link like so

[Profile Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD5Ns.png)

However, it is displaying the variable like so

[Profile Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qfHZ.png)

Here is the PHP

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username = '$username'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$userid = $row[0];
```

and the HTML

```
<a href="profile.php?id=$userid" style="position:relative; left:930px;"><h4><?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></h4></a>
```

I have also tried encasing it in PHP and echoing the HTML code however that did not work either. I am new to MySQLI does anyone know how this can work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `echo` your vars, if you want them to appear in the html. There is no auto substitution for PHP vars inside html.

```
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $userid; ?>" style="position:relative; left:930px;"><h4><?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></h4></a>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can say `<?= $userid ?>` to echo out a variable inside of HTML. (In PHP versions < 5.4, you may need to enable "short_open_tag" in the php.ini, but most production environments enable this setting by default.)

Comment: Writing code which require and ini option is always an bad idea - especially when you write code which runs on many environments

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing out `$userid` as plain text. You want to tell PHP to write out the *value* of the variable in the link.

Here is what you are looking for.

```
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $userid; ?>" style="position:relative; left:930px;"><h4><?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></h4></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $userid ?>" style="position:relative; left:930px;"><h4><?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></h4></a>
```